# Elasticsearch loses performance changing path.data running on SparkSQL

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, apache-spark, path

I'm using Elastisearch on a cluster with 4 nodes using SparkSQL. I'm trying to copy tables from the Hive-metastore to Elasticseach using saveToEs. 
Everything works good if I work with tables with size around 13Gb, but if I want to index a huge table with 60Gb or more something goes wrong.

The problem is that many executors should write on the only folder /var/lib/elastisearch and something goes wrong. Each node of cluster has 10 hard disk, so to improve parallelism I added to path.data more folders, each per disk, so at the end I had

```
path.data=/data1/elasticsearch,.......,/data10/elasticsearch
```

I restarted Elastic and everything was good. I checked the new configuration with

```
curl  http://namenode:9200/_nodes/settings?pretty
```

The problem is that with:

- the default path.data the index-speed is 1Gb per minute
- the new configuration speed is 1Gb per 2/2,5 minutes.

So with the second configuration I can index huge table (because the process doesn't crash), but Elastic is very slow, with the default configuration Elastic is very fast, but I cannot index table bigger than 15Gb. Is there something to configure?

I'm using Elasticsearch 2.3.2 on my cluster and Maven dependecy elasticsearch-hadoop: 2.3.2 to write the scala driver for Spark.

Thanks

Comment: Which version of Elasticsearch? The behavior of `path.data` differs between 1.x and 2.x.

Comment: Sorry, I added the version to my question. It's 2.3.2 version of Elasticsearch